# Wall of Flesh glitch

Tags: terraria

The Wall of Flesh keeps rising into the sky before it disappears completely!
It doesn't despawn when I die and I can't kill it since I can't reach its face

[image]

Comment: Umm, restart the server?

Comment: It's single player :c

Comment: This is a bug, you should go to the official Terraria forums and report it there. We can't help you with this here.

Comment: Does this comment contain more questions than the original post?

Answer (score 1):

Now, I'm not sure if this works, but I think it does:
Destroy your bridge across the underworld, or at least part of it.
I've seen a similar question to this before(possible duplicate) and it seems like destroying your bridge would help.

Also, if you manage to fix this problem, fighting the wall should be much easier, as it becomes "enraged" if it leaves the underworld.